# Parsing PDF file using Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to modify the contents of a PDF document using [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/). I used [this example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/ReplaceString.java) as it is, but observed that the text it my PDF file is getting split at character level (or worse). For example, a string,`EM? what it is:` gets split into:

```
COSString{E}
COSString{M?}
COSString{ }
COSString{w}
COSString{hat }
COSString{it }
COSString{is}
COSString{:}
```

(when checked by printing the `cosString` in the above mentioned code). As far as I can see, there are only Latin characters in the file, and the encoding is also ISO-8859-1. Any ideas?

Regards,

Salil

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a PDF formatting issue. That is how your particular PDF stores the text in order to get correct letter spacing or for [kerning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning). This varies greatly from PDF to PDF, depending on how they were created.

Typically, I would suggest simply merging all the different tokens into one big content string.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can technically do that, but think about the headache: First create the merged string, then search in it, then for each of the position, go there and replace it...

Since I have multiple strings to be replaced, this will cause unnecessary overhead. I tried with 2-3 different files, and got the same problem. I wonder how the example code works for others.

Comment: I would think there's code out there somewhere that has already solved this problem. I've never used PDFBox for modifying, personally, so I'm not sure.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help though. It is technically correct. +1 for that. I am not marking it as 'accepted' as of now.